# does mongodb supports multiget based on the id?

Tags: mongodb

How can I query for multiple documents using their _id

i.e., if i have an array of ids of  documents in a certain collection, how can i get all of these documents at once in a single operation

can i use something like:

```
db.collection.find({_id:[id1,id2,id3]})
```

and then mongodb return 3 documents of ids id1,id2,id3

is that possible, and if so, what is the exact syntax , or method , and is there any advices or precautions to take into consideration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `$in` operator as MongoDB [doc](http://ru.wiki.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in) says:

```
db.collection.find( { field : { $in : array } } );
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. The correct syntax is:

```
db.collection.find({ _id : { $in : [id1, id2, id3] } )
```

Comment: but, is this efficient? getting a document by id is very efficient,much more than any other query , even if it has an index on that field, does this query has the gt by id  efficiency  or normal query with index effieiency? thanks

Comment: It is as efficient as querying by any indexed field. In fact, MongoDB does not limit you in storing the '_id' in your own format. By the way, I haven't heard that here is any difference between the '_id' index and any other index. Where did you get that?